Jersey: "Falling back to injection-less client"
I'm bumping the dependencies I have on an old test harness to the latest versions. One of these dependencies is jersey-client which I've bumped to 3.1.6, which at the time of writing this is the last released version.
When I run the code I get the following warning in the application logs:
org.glassfish.jersey.client.innate.inject.NonInjectionManager <init>
WARNING: Falling back to injection-less client.

This message is written every time I make a REST call irrespective of the type of call (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE etc)
Clearly jersey is trying to tell me something it considers important, but it's not obvious what the problem is or what I should do about it. I've tried searching the warning message for some documentation on the issue; one search engine only drew up 6 hits (none of which where helpful), another failed to find any hits at all.
Apart from flooding the logs with unwanted messages (one for each call I make), my application appears to be working so there is no immediate problem. All the same, I'd still like to know what the problem is as it's almost always a bad idea to ignore warning messages.
Does anybody know what this message is referring to or how to fix it?

To the person who voted to close: Would you like to tell me what you want me to clarify.

I also think that the behaviour is poorly documented, but it seems that jersey would like to use an injection factory. After adding jersey's injection manager
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

as dependency, the message disappeared.
I don't know what exactly the advantage is, but maybe you can integrate jersey configurations or, for example, a logging filter via injection.

Thank you - it worked perfectly. As a matter of interest how did you find out about this dependency?

I actually don't remember that. I probably googled for jersey and injection and then found a reference to HK2.

Isabelle's answer is correct.
A bit of explanation - when HK2 is not on a classpath, Jersey would fail with an exception. Instead, as a fallback, the injection-less client is used. This approach works well for clients that do not use injection (@Context) in classes registered in those clients (for instance in the ClientRequestFilter).
For some scenarios, it can be a requirement not to depend on HK2 (when it is not needed) to minimize the application/microservice footprint.
Some people complain about the time the Jersey client takes to boot up before the first request can be sent. Without HK2, the time is about halved.
Another requirement would be to depend on pure CDI injection, which will possibly come in Jakarta REST 5.0 (I know, many years before then, it was postponed from the recent Jakarta REST 4.0). However, unlike with HK2, there is just a single CDI runtime for possible multiple clients - and the CDI beans related to each client are not isolated from the other clients. So one approach can be to use these injection-less clients.
When HK2 is missing, the client prints a warning about the non-functional injection in the client. If that's by purpose, the warning can be turned off by including
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.incubator</groupId>
     <artifactId>jersey-injectless-client</artifactId>
 </dependency>

In fact, by including this, Jersey picks the inject-less client no matter whether the HK2 is on the classpath or not. As you can see, this is still an incubating feature.
